# Автоматический подгон размеров окна и виджетов, под разное разрешение экрана (PyQt5)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

У меня имеется приложение написанное на python (с применением PyQt5). На моем мониторе (1366x768) все прекрасно видно. Если это же приложение запустить к примеру на другом компьютере с другим разрешением монитора, то ситуация уже чуть хуже. Подскажите пожалуйста как быть как :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код самого окна сделан через QtDesigner и .ui-файл конвертирован в .py-файл

`login.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\login.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.7
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(381, 260)
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 361, 241))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("border-radius:10px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(68, 56, 72);")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.registrate = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.registrate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 150, 231, 21))
        self.registrate.setStyleSheet("border-radius:10px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(170, 0, 255);\n"
"color:white;\n"
"")
        self.registrate.setObjectName("registrate")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 120, 231, 21))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("border-radius:10px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(170, 0, 255);\n"
"color:white;\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.closeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.closeButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 10, 22, 22))
        self.closeButton.setStyleSheet("border-radius:10px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(170, 0, 255);\n"
"color:white;\n"
"")
        self.closeButton.setObjectName("closeButton")
        self.closeButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.closeButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 10, 22, 22))
        self.closeButton_2.setStyleSheet("border-radius:10px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(170, 0, 255);\n"
"color:white;\n"
"")
        self.closeButton_2.setObjectName("closeButton_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 70, 231, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("border-radius:10px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(100, 83, 106);\n"
"padding-left:10px;")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 100, 231, 21))
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("border-radius:10px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(100, 83, 106);\n"
"padding-left:10px;")
        self.lineEdit_2.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.registrate.setText(_translate("Form", "Зарегистрироваться"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Авторизоваться"))
        self.closeButton.setText(_translate("Form", "X"))
        self.closeButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "_"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Form", "Логин"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Form", "Пароль"))
```

Comment: Здесь смотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576403/how-can-i-anchor-widgets-in-qt-creator

Comment: @Виктор: это не особо помогло :(

Comment: Вы якоря выставляли, и к сетке привязываи? Или что значит: не особо помогло?

Comment: pon4ik  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70872411/how-to-fit-the-windows-size-according-to-display-resolution